# A fair die and some ties in a wardrobe - formal argument needed

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A wardrobe $W_1$ contains $m$ black and $m$ blue ties. A fair die with $m$ sides is rolled. If the $r$th face appears, then $r$ ties are removed from the wardrobe $W_1$, and placed in **another** wardrobe $W_2$ (empty to begin with). Now, pick a tie from $W_2$ at random. What is the probability that it is a tie of black color?

*Quick guess:* $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$

Suppose $r$ ties are removed from $W_1$, and the tuple $(x,y)$ denotes how many ties of each color are removed. Here, $x+y = r$, $x$ represents black and $y$ represents blue ties. The possibilities for $(x,y)$ are as follows:
$$(0,r)\\ (1,r-1)\\ (2,r-2)\\ \vdots \\(r-2,2)\\(r-1,1)\\(r,0)\\\text{where } 1\le r\le m$$
There is an obvious inherent symmetry involved, i.e. if $(x_1,y_1)$ is a possibility, then so is $(y_1,x_1)$. This is what led me to think that the probability of picking a tie of black color from the second wardrobe is exactly $\frac{1}{2}$, since I found no reason to bias myself towards either of the colors. Is that some good intuition to count upon?

How would we formally evaluate $$\mathbf P(\text{Black tie is picked from }W_2) = ?$$
The following comes to mind:
$$\mathbf P(\text{Black tie is picked from }W_2) = \sum_{r=1}^m \mathbf P(\text{Black tie is picked from }W_2|r^{\text{th}} \text{ face appears on the die})$$
**Edit: Still looking for a formal argument.**

Comment: What is the procedure to choose $r $ ties to replace?

Comment: There is no replacement? You basically pick $r$ ties from the first wardrobe and put them in the second. Then, you forget about the first wardrobe and pick a tie from the second one. You want to know the odds of it being a black tie!

Comment: One can pick only blue ties. Then the probability to pick a black tie from the 2nd wardrobe is 0.

Comment: What? Why can you only pick blue ties? I think you've misunderstood the problem.

Comment: No. I don't misunderstand. What prevents one to choose only blue ties?

Comment: This is a question of **probability**. Nothing prevents you, it's just that **other possibilities** exist - which for unknown reasons, you choose to disregard.

Comment: Why do they exist? Let say I am the person who removes the ties from the 1st wardrobe and I decide that I remove only blue ties.

Comment: @user Once again, that is just **one of the possibilities**. There are several others in which you do remove both blue and black ties! Please rethink what the sample space involved here is. $r$ is not fixed, by the way. $r$ is a random variable, which depends on the roll of the die. Once the die roll fixes some $r$ for the given situation, there are $r+1$ possibilities as I have listed in my question.

Comment: Why don't you assume that the probability to remove blue tie  from the first wardrobe is equal to 1? Try this number and you will see that the probability to pick the blue tie from the second wardrobe is also equal to 1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability is ${1\over2}$, by symmetry: Whatever calculation you do to answer the question for "black" is also valid for your friend, who was asked to compute the probability for "blue".

Comment: You obviously  assume that the probability to choose a black tie for replacing from the first wardrobe into the second one is $\frac12$ but this was not given. Actually the procedure of choosing the $r $ ties was not described at all.

Comment: @user: I'm talking about the overall probability for the full story.

Comment: But if only black ties are moved to the second wardrobe (independent of $r $) the answer cannot be $\frac12$. Actually it depends on the probability to choose the black ties from the first wardrobe which is NOT given.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the formula for the Expected Value for a binomial random variable r ~ E(r) =
P(r) * r , where P(r) is probability of success, r is number of trials.

When we remove r ties randomly from W1 with m black and m blue ties,  we expect $\frac{m}{m+m}r $=$\frac{1}{2 }r $ blue ties and $\frac{m}{m+m}r$=$\frac{1}{2 }r $ black ties removed.

Similarly, if we pick up 1 tie randomly from W2, we expect $\frac{r/2}{r/2+r/2}x1=\frac{1}{2 }$ black tie picked, or the probability to pick a black tie is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your argument, could you elaborate? Are you trying to use "expectation of random variables" somehow?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer to clarify this.